# java.lang.VerifyError in YouTube service initialization

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

I'm trying to develop app working with YouTube. First, I downloaded gdata libs from
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list (client, core, media and youtube), then tried to instantiate `YouTubeService` as in Google's tutorial:

```
service = new YouTubeService(id, key);
```

But when I tried to launch my app I got this:

```
ERROR/dalvikvm(5289): Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaStreamSource', referenced from method com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource
ERROR/dalvikvm(5289): Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaMultipart', referenced from method com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService
```

libs are attached to project and I can see those "missing" classes in them, and my IDE can see them, but there's something strange happens in runtime. Any ideas where I'm spoiled?

P.S. It's Android app, if it matters.

Comment: Did you get solution ?

Comment: @KetanAhir nope, sorry

Comment: It's okay...but I have fixed it.

Comment: @KetanAhir add your solution as answer, may be it will help somebody

Comment: I have added many jars (not sure which is required) and now removing one by one.So post it later on.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the probem by adding the following libraries:
activation.jar
additionnal.jar
android-support-v4.jar
guava-r07.jar
mail.jar
beside the gdata libraries:
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
Not need authetntication.